# how to fetch data from php and display in android listview in FRAGMENT?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Error throwing in `onPostExecute()`:

> The constructor SimpleAdapter(Commodities,
>   ArrayList>, int, String[], int[]) is
>   undefined

The problem is in `onPostExecute()` of my `AsyncTask`:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Commodities.this,
                    matchFixtureList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                            TAG_SCRIPT, TAG_BUYSELL, TAG_TRADESELL, TAG_TARGET,
                            TAG_STOPLOSS, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
                            R.id.Script, R.id.BuySell, R.id.TradeSell,
                            R.id.Target, R.id.StopLoss, R.id.Status });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

How can I solve this error?  Here is the whole class code:

```
public class Commodities extends ListFragment {

    private String URL_ITEMS = "http://ourvadodara.ddns.net/NeptuneFinsol/commodities_fetch.php";
    private static final String TAG_COMMODITIES = "commodities";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_SCRIPT = "script";
    private static final String TAG_BUYSELL = "buysell";
    private static final String TAG_TRADESELL = "tradesell";
    private static final String TAG_TARGET = "target";
    private static final String TAG_STOPLOSS = "stoploss";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";


    JSONArray matchFixture = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matchFixtureList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bank__details,
                container, false);
        new GetFixture().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
            Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,
                    ServiceHandler.GET);
            // print the json response in the log
            Log.d("Get match fixture response: ", "> " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("try", "in the try");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COMMODITIES);
                    Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                    int len = matchFixture.length();
                    Log.d("len", "get array length");
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Script = c.getString(TAG_SCRIPT);
                        Log.d("Script", Script);
                        String BuySell = c.getString(TAG_BUYSELL);
                        Log.d("BuySell", BuySell);
                        String TradeSell = c.getString(TAG_TRADESELL);
                        Log.d("TradeSell", TradeSell);
                        String Target = c.getString(TAG_TARGET);
                        Log.d("Target", Target);
                        String StopLoss = c.getString(TAG_STOPLOSS);
                        Log.d("StopLoss", StopLoss);
                        String Status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        Log.d("Status", Status);

                        // hashmap for single match
                        HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_SCRIPT, Script);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_BUYSELL, BuySell);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TRADESELL, TradeSell);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TARGET, Target);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_STOPLOSS, StopLoss);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_STATUS, Status);
                        matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Commodities.this,
                    matchFixtureList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                            TAG_SCRIPT, TAG_BUYSELL, TAG_TRADESELL, TAG_TARGET,
                            TAG_STOPLOSS, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
                            R.id.Script, R.id.BuySell, R.id.TradeSell,
                            R.id.Target, R.id.StopLoss, R.id.Status });
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Commodities` is a `ListFragment`, you can't use `this` as a `Context`.

Try using `Commodities.this.getActivity()` instead of `Commodities.this`

```
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Commodities.this.getActivity(),
                matchFixtureList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                        TAG_SCRIPT, TAG_BUYSELL, TAG_TRADESELL, TAG_TARGET,
                        TAG_STOPLOSS, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Script, R.id.BuySell, R.id.TradeSell,
                        R.id.Target, R.id.StopLoss, R.id.Status });
```

The `Context` that you need here is the `Activity` that contains this `ListFragment`.

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])), the first parameter of the constructor is:

> **context**  The context where the View associated with this SimpleAdapter
>   is running

Another thing to note is that you will need to use `Commodities.this` when you call `setListAdapter()`:

```
 //setListAdapter(adapter); //won't work
 Commodities.this.setListAdapter(adapter); //use this instead
```

This is because `setListAdapter()` is a method of `ListFragment` here, [see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)).

Comment: If i want to use extends FRAGMENT then what all change should i do?

Comment: @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Commodities.this.getActivity(),
     matchFixtureList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
       TAG_SCRIPT, TAG_BUYSELL, TAG_TRADESELL, TAG_TARGET,
       TAG_STOPLOSS, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
       R.id.Script, R.id.BuySell, R.id.TradeSell,
       R.id.Target, R.id.StopLoss, R.id.Status });
   setListAdapter(adapter);}                                                                         if i want to use fragment instead of ListFragment then?

Comment: yes it got working when i use ListFragment but if i use extends Fragment then error throws setListAdapter that (The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type Commodities.GetFixture) @DanielNugent

Comment: can you show me how to do that? can you let me know the code if possible. Please send me code. I am new in the field of android

Comment: can i get your email address. please revert me your email address on iphonic.pre@live.com so that i can sent you my file. Need help

Comment: @PritiRathod You really have to just stay on the StackOverflow site.  I would recommend working on it a bit more yourself, who knows you might get it working on your own! Make sure to search the site, there are a lot of questions already answered that will help you! If you really get stuck, ask a new question, and explain exactly what you are stuck on, make sure it's a good question.  If it's good you will get upvotes!  Comment here if you post a new question, and I'll take a look!

Comment: and you let me any easy way to display data on Fragment... ?

Comment: @PritiRathod Also see my other answer here, it will definitely help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116031/listfragment-in-android-studio/29116202#29116202