# How to display listView in fragment class?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I'm new in android programming. I want to try to make simple tab layout app using **fragment**, how to display listView in a fragment? , I have googled and found a solution but it not using fragment class. I can show webview but how to  show a listVIew

My tab1 class:

```
       public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // get the url to open
        // set up the WebView
        webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        return v;
    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My tab2 class ( i want to display listView  here):

```
    public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

The// ListView activity needs to extend activity class, it doesn't work in a fragment, how to display in a fragment?
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Fragment adapter:

> public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
>
> ```
> CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
> int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
>
>
> // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
> public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
>     super(fm);
>
>     this.Titles = mTitles;
>     this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
>
> }
>
> //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
> @Override
> public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>
>     if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
>     {
>         Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
>         return tab1;
>     }
>     else   //if (position == 1)       // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
>     {
>         Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
>         return tab2;
>     } //        else //        { //            NewKasus newKasus = new NewKasus(); //            return newKasus; //        }
>
> }
>
> // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
>
> @Override
> public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>     return Titles[position];
> }
>
> // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return NumbOfTabs;
> } }
> ```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
//


    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Berita","Kasus","Add Kasus"};
    int Numboftabs =3;


    //
   // bawaaan materal tab
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Take a look at the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116031/listfragment-in-android-studio/29116202#29116202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am giving you simple example of showing list In Fragment.

your fragment first...

```
public class Tab1 extends ListFragment { 
String[] list_items;    

Tab1(){
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
    list_items= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_items);

 return rootView;
}
}
```

in your strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="list">
         <item>item1</item>
         <item>item1</item>
         <item>item1</item>
         <item>item1</item>
         <item>item1</item>
  </string-array>
```

your tab_1 layout have to have.. listView. with id **android:list**
this is only necessary when you extend your fragment with **ListFragment** class. 
If you simply extend with **Fragment** then you won't need to add this specific id **android:list**.

for this example i am giving you need following in your layout...

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

this is all you need to create listView in fragment.

In your case, you get the data in array and then pass it in listView.
Here in example i used  locally. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What is the source of your data? If you are using ordinary Strings, you could just do it in your `onCreateView` method, the same way you'd do it in an Activity.

If you are getting the data from a database or network, you'd be better off doing it in the `onPostExecute` method of an AsyncTask